Snowflake - reference variable as part of column name
I am new to Snowflake and trying to use a set variable to call a column name. Here's what I'm currently trying:
set macro = 'Aut_24';

Select *
from my_data1 a
left join mydata2 b on a.id = b.id
where CAST("b.Column_name_$macro_value" AS DECIMAL(15,2)) >= 50

But I get the error "Invalid Identifier". Does anyone know how to fix this?

You would need to use dynamic SQL i.e. construct the SQL statement and then execute it

@NickW I've not done this before, do you know of a beginner guide I could follow? Thanks.

I would start here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-construct-at-runtime

You can try this way using identifier or as @NickW suggested try dynamic SQL.
create table my_data1(id varchar, fld1 varchar);
create or replace table my_data2(id varchar, fld1 varchar, "Column_name_Aut_24" varchar);


    set macro = '"Column_name_Aut_24"';
    Select *
    from my_data1 a
    left join my_data2 b on a.id = b.id
    where identifier($macro)  >= 50;

